# How to skip certain line from Text file in java?

Tags: java, io, out-of-memory

I am currently learning Java and I have faced this problem where I want to load a file that consists a huge number of lines (I am reading the file line by line ) and the thing I want to do is skip certain lines (pseudo-code).

```
the line thats starts with (specific word such as "ABC")
```

I have tried to use

```
if(line.startwith("abc"))
```

But that didn't work. I am not sure if I am doing it wrong, that's why I am here asking for a help, below part of the load function:

```
public String loadfile(.........){

//here goes the variables 

try {

        File data= new File(dataFile);
        if (data.exists()) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile));
            while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {                        
                if (thisLine.length() > 0) {
                    tmpLine = thisLine.toString();
                    tmpLine2 = tmpLine.split(......);
                    [...]
```

Comment: +1.  Not sure why this was voted down, but putting back to 0.

Comment: -1 nothing to do with java-ee servlets or jsp and a copy of an already deleted post

Comment: +1 not sure whay voted down. if there are wrong tags, just correct them...

Comment: You say a specific word such as ABC, both in you if-statement you check for abc. These are not equal, and one way to solve this is to for example to transform the statement to uppercase. If the case does not matter to you.

Comment: New user posting.  If you're going to vote down, at least provide feedback.

Comment: I gave feedback. This post is an exact duplicate of the one I've corrected 5min ago. That one was deleted while I was formatting and editing it.

Comment: Yes sir, the case doesn't matter to me , whatever it could be " uppercase or lowercase" as long as i read the whole file line by line and if it happens that the certain line starts with (abc or ABC) i should skip it.thank you

Comment: Mr.Chuetback, i am really sorry that i had deleted the post before i saw your feedback , i was just re-posting it,accept my apology and i truly appreciate your help.

Comment: @user796418  Please edit questions, rather than delete/repost them.  Doing so seems to have created a lot of confusion, on this question alone.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I understood and i will keep your advise in mind.Truly appreciated

Comment: @ckuetbach, that comment wasn't referred to you but the one who rated him down without putting feedback initially.

Comment: I voted him down (Thats why I wrote -1 ...)

Comment: I think my downvote was really good for his reputation. I doubt a question like this would get upveted 6 times.

Comment: @ckuetbach sir i've already apologized to you ,i don't know why you taken this so personal , all i asked is help , if you are upset because i deleted the post , i am truly sorry for that :).be cool and try to help if  you could ,it's all for the sake of learning.thank you

Comment: *"this problem where i want to load a file that consists a huge number of data ( i am reading the file line by line ) and the thing i want to do.."*  Woah up there.  Is the real problem not *"how to process the file without producing an `OutOfMemoryError`?"*.  If that is the case, there might be entirely different strategies that can be used, like for example: processing each line, then 'forgetting' it (by clearing it from memory.

Comment: No problem... I was just a litte consfused, as I reformattet, edited and answered your first question and it has been deleted, exact that second I tried to click "send" and than it appeared the next second again. I removed my -1

Comment: Most of what @ckuetbach has done is try to help you get better answers, they provide good advice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson True that, i have faced the OutOfMemoryError but i have overcome the problem by 1-Inspecting the memory and the heap size using VisualVM and i have increased the heap size for jvm.now is the small issue which is checking the first word in the file if it's for example (abc) then skip.thank you

Comment: @ckuetbach Thank you so much , sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(­"ABC")){
    //skip line
} else {
    //do something
}
```

This will converts the `line` to all the Upper Characters by using function `toUpperCase()`   and will check whether the string starts with `ABC` .

And if it is `true` then it will do nothing(skip the line) and go into the `else` part.

You can also use `startsWithIgnoreCase` which is a function provided by the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) . It takes the two string arguments.

```
public static boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String str,
                                           String prefix)
```

This function return boolean.
And checks whether a String starts with a specified prefix.

It return true if the String starts with the prefix , case insensitive.

Comment: This. not sure if he just gave us quick psuedocode or it was actually what he was doing, but `startwith` is not the same as `startsWith` and `abc` is not the same as `ABC`

Answer (score 2):

If the case isn't important try using the `StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(String str,
                                           String prefix)` of [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/)

```
This function return boolean.
```

[See javadoc here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#startsWithIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Usage:

```
if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(­line, "abc")){
    //skip line
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Seems like overkill for the 'one-liner' posted by vikiii.

Comment: Very true. 
I do think it's important that novice Java programmers learn Apache Commons library as soon as possible, so they don't rewrite common Utility.

Comment: Having done exactly that on a few occasions, I now see your point.

Answer (score 1):

If you have large a input File, you code will create a `OutOfMemoryError`. there is nothing you can do against it without editing te code (adding more memory will fail, if the file gets bigger).

I beleave you store the selected lines in memory. If the file gets lager (2GB or so) you'll have 4GB in memory. (The old Value of the `String` and the new one).

You have to work with streams to solve this.

Create a `FileOutpuStream`, and write the selcted line into that Stream.

Your method must be changed. For a large input yo cannot return a String:

```
public String loadfile(...){
```

You can return a `Stream` or a file.

```
public MyDeletingLineBufferedReader loadFile(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use:**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    String lineString;
    try{
    while((lineString = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (lineString.toUpperCase().startsWith(­"abc")){
            //skip
            } else {
            //do something
            }
        }
     }
```

***or***

`static boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String str, String prefix)` method in *org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils* like below.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
       String lineString;
        try{
            while((lineString = br.readLine()) != null) {
               if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(­lineString, "abc")){
                //skip
                } else {
                //do something
                }
              }
           }
```